# SQL Server 2016 Read Only Replica With Different Database Security

Tags: sql-server, cluster-computing, sql-server-2016, readonly, failover

Is it possible to have a SQL 2016 read only replica that is not used as a fail over server with different database security than the primary?

I want to ensure that the users don't have access to the primary node and only have read-only access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a SQL 2016 read only replica that is not used as a fail over server

Yes. But you need to elaborate. For example, if it is in asynchronous mode, you can only do manual failovers. This is *sort of* like not using it as a fail over server, since you would have to physically force it. See [failover and failover modes.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/failover-and-failover-modes-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017)

> Is it possible to have a SQL 2016 read only replica with different
>   database security than the primary

Yes. In fact, one of the annoying parts of AlwaysOn AG's is syncing logons. Most people want them to match. That's why [many people have blogged ways](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/11/30/sql-server-alwayson-availability-groups-script-sync-logins-replicas/) on how to do this, and others [have created tools](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Sync-DbaAvailabilityGroup) in powershell to do this, as well as sync agent jobs, alerts, etc.

> I want to ensure that the users don't have access to the primary node

Since replicas sit on different servers as the primary, you can keep the permissions separate across the instances easily. Just give your users a logon to the replica instance and database, and not the primary instance and database. Remember there is a difference in the server logon and the user mapping. For your RoR, your user will need a server logon and then have their userid mapped to your replica.

> I want to ensure that the users only have read-only access.

Since it is already read-only, that's the only access they would have. They wouldn't be able to UPDATE / DELETE / INSERT even if they were sysadmins (unless, of course they changed it our of read-only)

Comment: We have analytics users who require access to production data although do not want them impacting production systems.  Currently on a nightly basis we back up all databases and restore them onto "Reporting" databases then apply scripts to change the security to grant them access.  We currently have an always on synchronous cluster with automatic fail over.  I would like to either use the existing secondary as a read only node or create a third asynchronous read only not a used for fail over at all where that these users can query.  I would like minimum impact on production performance.

Comment: Just to confirm as replication occurs at the database level can I define different security on the databases themselves or does it have to be done at the server level?

Comment: You can do this at the database level. You can actually go as far as the object level and grant access to only certain tables if you’d like. You can also use row level security if you wanted to get even more granular.